# Standard Model Effective Field Theory: when studying SMEFT, are we looking for deviations?

Tags: standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model, effective-field-theory

The Standard Model consists of renormalizable interactions (dimension 4) between the known fermions and bosons.

The Standard Model Effective Field Theory (SMEFT) includes additional higher dimension operators (for example, the famous dimension 5 Weinberg which gives neutrinos masses, and then after that **lots** of dimension 6 operators and so on...). These higher dimension operators are suppressed by larger and larger powers of some heavy mass scale (and so their effects are weaker and weaker with increasing dimension).

It is clear to me that the SMEFT is well-defined, at least in the sense that people know how to make physical predictions with it (for cross-sections and so on).

My question is somewhat soft: What is the "point" of studying the SMEFT?

Is it that we have such precise predictions for observables, that we can further test the accuracy of the Standard model - eventually so we can detect deviations from the standard model predictions, to see if there is actually some different particle content at higher energies than we would expect (inferred from the Standard Model content we see at low energies through the SMEFT)?

Some insight into why the SMEFT is interesting to study would be appreciated.

Comment: There  are discrepancies in some cases with predictions of the standard model. That is why more and more experiments are planned, see this https://indico.cern.ch/event/507180/contributions/2168660/attachments/1304362/1948698/Open_questions_PP.pdf

Comment: An organized/systematic  [glimpse](https://indico.cern.ch/event/754031/contributions/3218239/attachments/1931600/3199341/BLV19_Sanz_SMEFT.pdf) into possible UV sectors beyond our reach.